# dividir cadena separado por una coma y validar si es igual

Tags: php

este es el codigo que tengo

variable que traigo de la base de datos
$perfil['imagen'];<--- en esta variable puedo traer varias opciones  por ejemplo:

```
presentable,aseado
presentable,aseado,De traje
Presentable,aseado,uniforme
```

entonces si por ejemplo  la variable trae presentable,aseado en el option quisiera hacer un  `if($perfil['imagen'] == 'presentable'){ //codigo}`

**algo parecido a esto si me pudieran dar un ejemplo**

```
$perfil['imagen'];
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'presentable'){ echo "selected";} value="presentable">Presentable</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'aseado'){ echo "selected";} value="aseado">Aseado</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'traje'){ echo "selected";} value="traje">Traje</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'condicion saludable'){ echo "selected";} value="condicion saludable">Condicion saludable</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'sin tatuajes'){ } value="sin tatuajes">Sin tatuajes</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'sin percing'){ } value="sin percing">Sin percing</option>
                    <option if($perfil['imagen'] == 'sin expansiones'){ } value="sin expansiones">Sin expansiones</option>
```

quisiera algo parecido a esto validar si es igual el valor de la varible $perfil['experiencia'] que viene de la base de datos conalguno de los valores del option

es un ejemplo que hice pero la variable $perfil['experiencia'](6 meses) solo traia un valor

```
$perfil['experiencia'] == "6 meses" 
                      <option <?php if($perfil['experiencia'] == "6 meses"){ echo "selected"; } ?> value="6 meses">6 meses</option>
                      <option <?php if($perfil['experiencia'] == "1 año"){ echo "selected"; } ?> value="1 año">1 año</option>
                      <option <?php if($perfil['experiencia'] == "2 años"){ echo "selected"; } ?> value="2 años">2 años</option>
                      <option <?php if($perfil['experiencia'] == "5 años"){ echo "selected"; } ?> value="5 años">3 años</option>
```

aqui esta la solucion que necesitaba para validar los opcion la pregunta correcta era buscar dentro de un array si la palabra x existia
     value="presentable">Presentable

Comment: Revisa esta documentación sobre **explode** http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Comment: @Cig si sabías la respuesta, ¿por qué no ponerla como respuesta? Los comentarios no se indexan y podrían hacer que tu respuesta se perdiera. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour].

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro creo que stackoverflow en su sona de comentarios se encuentra mal implementado y es el autor de la pregunta quien deba resolver sus dudas y ponerlas el mismo como respuesta. Ese es mi punto de vista. Y esto porque? debido a la influencia de stackoverflow en los nuevos programadores, ellos estan esperando que alguien les resuelva la vida sin antes ellos buscar una solución. Slds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar la función [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), es decir, divide una cadena en varios cadenas.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
//Tu variable $perfil['experiencia']
$data = 'presentable,aseado,uniforme';

//Divide una cadena.
$cadena = explode(",", $data);      

//Recorrer array
foreach ($cadena as $valor) {       
    if ($valor == 'presentable') {
        //Sigues con tu codigo
    } 
}
```

Tu segunda pregunta, no me quedo claro del todo que función quieres crear realmente. A ver si aun así te puedo orientar un poco con él `foreach`.

```
//Recorrer array y creamos inputs segun 'valor'.
foreach ($cadena as $valor) {       
    if ($valor == 'presentable') {
        echo "<option value=$valor selected>$valor</option>";               
    } elseif ($valor == 'aseado') {
        echo "<option value=$valor selected>$valor</option>";
    } else {
        //Default valores.
    }
}
```

> Al final *@CarlosEnriqueGilGil* ha solucionado su segunda pregunta de la siguiente forma.

Añadir el atributo `selected` a tu `option` en caso si existe en nuestro arreglo (`$cadena`).

```
<?php

//Tu variable $perfil['imagen']
$data = 'presentable,aseado,uniforme';

//Dividir una cadena.
$cadena = explode(",", $data);      

#Añadir el atributo 'selected' en caso si existe en nuestro arreglo ($cadena) mediante la función
#in_Array(), es decir, comprueba si un valor existe en un array.
echo"<option "; if(in_array("presentable",$cadena)) echo 'selected';  echo " value='presentable'>Presentable</option>\n";
echo"<option "; if(in_array("aseado",$cadena)) echo 'selected';  echo " value='aseado'>Aseado</option>\n";
echo"<option "; if(in_array("de traje",$cadena)) echo 'selected';  echo " value='de_traje'>De traje</option>\n";
```

*Resultado:*

```
<option selected value='presentable'>Presentable</option>
<option selected value='aseado'>Aseado</option>
<option  value='de_traje'>De traje</option>
```

[`DEMO`](https://ideone.com/PrOXJd)

Comment: poero en los option como lo pongo en el foreach recorria 3 veces 1-'presentable,  2- aseado, 3 -uniforme'  y hay 8 opcion lo estoy viendo mal pienso si entiendo tu codigo pero no se como aplicarlo me puedes explicar por favor

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil podrías modificar tu pregunta, y poner un ejemplo que es lo que quieres lograr con tus `option` según el valor del `foreach`, ya que no sé qué quieres hacer realmente.

Comment: si ya lo hice, disculpa

Comment: Disculpa @CarlosEnriqueGilGil aun no lo he entendido bien, sé que quieres seleccionar un `option` según el valor de tu *Base de Datos*, ahora mi pregunta es `ninguna` o `6 meses` etc., también está en la misma variable que `if($perfil['experiencia'] == 'presentable')` ? sería algo así (Presentable,aseado,uniforme,6meses,etc)?

Comment: no ese es el ejemplo que hice y te mostre como hice el if , si se pudiera hacer con tu ejemplo algo parecido  como tu dices <option if(valor == '''presentable'){ echo 'selected'} value="presentable">Presentable</option>

Comment: ya modifique un poco como lo necesito puedes ver la variable imagen por favor

Comment: Creo que sería mejor hacer esto con una función que reciba los dos parámetros a comparar y si lo encuentra devuelva lo que quiere mostrar en la parte visible del `option` así como en el `value` del mismo. Lo que pasa es que la pregunta no está planteada con toda la claridad que se requeriría para una respuesta óptima.

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil te he puesto un segundo ejemplo, a ver si logro orientarte un poco, ya que como dice *A.Cedano* no está claro del todo lo que quieres lograr. Siempre podrías intentar crear el código con el ejemplo `foreach` y si se te presenta un nuevo problema, podrías crear una nueva pregunta, con más detalle.

Comment: si gracias, pero si no existe $valor == 'presentable' el option no aparece, ya  modifique mi ejemplo tambien creo que es entendible lo que necesito

Comment: gracias por la solucion de separar por comas una cadena  y la otra solucion fue muy facil me falto pensar <option  <?php if(in_array("presentable",$cadena)){echo "selected"; } ?> value="presentable">Presentable</option>

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil he puesto tu solución a tu segunda pregunta a mi respuesta, así le podrá servir a otros, un saludo.